# User index show users multiple times

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I've got a total of 11 users in my seeds.rb. however, in my user index, it displays 11x11 = 121 users. each user is listed 11 times. Also, whenever I create a new user on the website (sign up), it keeps on multiplying. +1 signed up user leads to a total of 12 users in the db and 12x12 = 144 users being displayed (THEY ARE NOT IN THE DB!) in the index... what's wrong here?! I checked my users controller create action for any weird stuff but couldn't find anything out of the usual.. any help?

this is my user index view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Users') %>
<h1>List of Users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= render @users %>
<% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Comment: Two things are clear here: 1. Your code contains at least one error. 2. Your question lacks important information (your code).

Comment: updated, see original question

Comment: `render @users` will display all users. You are currently doing this in a loop for each user (so for each existing user, you output every existing user).

Comment: okay i see... deleting the whole line will return no users at all however. Can u tell me what I should use instead please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Solarflare mentioned in the comment, you're rendering the entire user list (`@users`) at every iteration of that loop.  You should update your loop to be:

```
<ul class="users">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= render user %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

That way you're rendering the page for each individual `user` in the loop.

Comment: Or (more common in this case as there is no partial evaulation required), remove the loop and just leave `render users`.